# Is there a trick to build docker container with privilege option?

Tags: docker

I have to add some rule to `iptables`, in the build process it give me an error because i need `privilege` so is there any way to get around it,
i know that there no `privilege` option in `build`, or can i build and image without run it ?

Answer (score 2):

It's considered better practice from what I understand to use specific kernel capabilities:

```
docker run --cap-add NET_ADMIN <image> <command>
```

should get you what you need. You may need to also add `SYS_ADMIN` as well.

Comment: i want it in build time not in run time

Comment: Unfortunately you have to add these flags during runtime.

Comment: As a follow-up, see this thread for more information on the status of this feature: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1916